# Float text to the right of D3.Js Graph

Tags: d3.js, css-float, paragraph

I'm trying to float a paragraph of text to the right of D3.Js graph that I've inserted to the left:

[image: Picture of Graph]

So far, the text is at the right, but it still hovers below it, instead of fully to the right of it, lateral to it. I was wondering if there was a way to do it to get it to wrap fully.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `flex row`:

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
  <svg width="..." height="..."> ... Your graph is here ... </svg>
  <p style="margin-left: ...px;"> ... You paragraph text is here ... </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This was a perfect solution!

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark the answer as correct.